# Exporting Vue individual components as Web Components

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-4

I have a Vue app I've put together over the last few days defining a set of components that will be embedded into another app; the Vue app is for rapid development and acts as a test harness for the components.

I've now come to the point of adding these components to the main non-Vue app for which they are intended. I know I can build Web Components with `npm run build -- --target wc`, but I don't want to build the whole test harness app into a single component; rather, I want to build individual Vue components from the app into separate redistributable Web Components.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

With [@vue/cli-service-global](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-service-global) (currently in beta), you can indeed build [Web Components](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/build-targets.md#web-component) from your Vue SFC.

You can skip your ("test harness") app by specifying your components files as a [glob in the entry CLI argument](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/build-targets.md#bundle-that-registers-multiple-web-components):

```shell
$ vue-cli-service build --target wc --name foo 'src/components/*.vue'
```

However this will still build a single JS file containing all your Custom Elements.

You can further decouple these individual elements in *chunks* by using the [Async Web Components](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/build-targets.md#async-web-component) target instead (i.e. `wc-async` instead of `wc`):

```shell
$ vue-cli-service build --target wc-async --name foo 'src/components/*.vue'
```

Then you include the generated `foo.js` loader file as a `<script>` in your HTML file. It will define all your Custom Elements but not load them before they appear in the DOM.

Comment: Getting this error 'Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel', after running command 'vue-cli-service build --target wc --name my-custom-element 'src/components/*.vue'. I am using latest version of vue-cli.

Comment: @MangeshDaundkar Please feel free to open a new question with specific details of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the answer is to use the official [@vue/web-component-wrapper](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-web-component-wrapper) library.